# Keyboard interrupt on Turbo C++ 3.1

Tags: c++, keyboard, interrupt, dos, turbo-c++

My name is Andrea. I'm using Turbo C++ on an old PII 350 MHz with dos 7. I've written a while cycle which does something. I have to check a which letter of the keyboard has been pressed without checking it in the cycle in order to avoid it to slow down. Is there a way to set an interrupt like in arduino to stop the cycle only when a key is pressed?
I've tried with bioskey(0) in the cycle but it slows it down too much....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getch()` function in `<conio.h>`, which pauses program execution until one key is pressed, and returns the character of the pressed key.

Example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    puts("Hello World, press any key to continue.");
    getch();
    puts("Finished");
    

    return 0;
}
```

Note that `<conio.h>` is a non-standard library. The `<conio.h>` library and the function are also available in modern versions of Visual C++, but [the function is called `_getch()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/getch-getwch?view=msvc-170).

Comment: I think she wants the program to continue *until* a key is pressed, and getch() would block every time. You'd want to check kbhit() first, and only when it says a key has been pressed would you call getch(). I don't know about the Turbo C implementation of kbhit(), but djgpp simply compares the bytes indicating the start and end of keystrokes in the buffer, which is quite fast.